# Laravel socialite login through facebook results in Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I have a laravel project that uses facebook login. But after a few days of testing, when I go to the route, it says `Sorry, something went wrong.`. I did not touch or modified my code and as well as in the app in my facebook developers account. Can someone tell me what happened?

Here is my controller

```
    public function redirectToProvider(){
        $facebookScope = [
            'pages_manage_posts',
            'pages_read_engagement',
            'instagram_basic',
            'pages_show_list',
            'manage_pages',
            'publish_to_groups',
            'groups_access_member_info',
        ];
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes($facebookScope)->redirect();
    }

    public function facebook(){
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
            // dd($user);
            // $this->getPages($user);
            $this->getGroups($user);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json($e);
        }
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/fb','FacebookController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/facebookAuth','FacebookController@facebook');
```

My facebook app oauth setting
[image]

What the result look like

[image]

Laravel version: `6.2`

Socialite verion: `^4.4`

UPDATE: If i remove all the scopes, I can successfully  login and get the credentials and the token. But why the scopes is not working?

Comment: What is the mode of your application? Is it dev or live? Moreover, can you please try after  setting app_debug mode as true in the .env fiel of the laravel project to get the proper error message?

Comment: Not sure if this might cause the issue, but I am not able to find "manage_page" scope in the official permissions reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference
Can you double-check?

Comment: As prev comment suggests the scope is called "manage_pages". Try adding a "s" in the end

Comment: @Johan if I try to add an 's' to pages. it got me an error of 
`Invalid Scopes: pages_manage_posts, pages_read_engagement, manage_pages, publish_to_groups.`

Comment: it is on dev sir @Helper

Comment: hey i think u need to use local `https` url

Answer (score 2):

This error do not specify what has gone wrong so its hard to tackle but you can check the logs for detail error report it will surely help you. The logs are located in storage directory. If you want laravel to display complete error for you rather than the cryptic 'Whoops' message, make sure in your `.env` `APP_ENV=local` is in there and your `APP_DEBUG=true` or you can tweak it in your `config/app.php` like

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Comment: its already set to true. seems the issue is on socialite

Answer (score 1):

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

and run `php artisan config:cache`  command

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Who has asked this question already has the experience, is it necessary to go out too much?

Answer (score 0):

actually you are on production server and that's why the error is not showing on there.
Try to change the environment variable `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file and check the exact error. it maybe due to Socialite package which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can resolve this issue by just checking your request params in URL , in the scope=email%2Cpages_read_engagement%2C ETC ,
Just remove the email%2C and magic will happen .
Because we are not requesting the email but we are requesting the other permission which could be in the URL but not an email .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just posted an answer to another question where my issue was down to an inactive "email" use case permission in the Facebook app settings.

Posting it here incase it helps someone:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76768660/3102301

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34747640)

Answer (score -1):

just delete facebook site cookies and it will be solved