# Error "Sorry, something went wrong." while logging in facebook laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, facebook

I have implemented authorization through facebook using laravel.
When I am on the site, and I click on the authorization button via facebook, then there is a redirect to the page with the error "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPGa.png)
Already spent almost all, and did not find a solution for this problem.

URL where the error is located https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=2040703196275670&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgrowexspeak.space%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code

I leave the authorization code through facebook made through on Laravel.

FacebookController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class FaceBookController extends Controller
{
    public function loginUsingFacebook()
    {
       $facebook_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();

       return $facebook_user;
    }
     public function callbackFromFacebook()
     {
      try {
           $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

           $saveUser = User::updateOrCreate([
               'facebook_id' => $user->getId(),
           ],[
               'name' => $user->getName(),
               'email' => $user->getEmail(),
               'password' => Hash::make($user->getName().'@'.$user->getId())
                ]);

           Auth::loginUsingId($saveUser->id);

           return redirect()->route('home');
           } catch (\Throwable $th) {
              throw $th;
           }
       }

}
```

config/services.php

```
facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '####', //USE FROM FACEBOOK DEVELOPER ACCOUNT
        'client_secret' => '####', //USE FROM FACEBOOK DEVELOPER ACCOUNT
        'redirect' => 'https://growexspeak.space/facebook/callback'
    ],
```

Web.php

```
Route::prefix('facebook')->name('facebook.')->group( function(){
    Route::get('auth', [FaceBookController::class, 'loginUsingFacebook'])->name('login');
    Route::get('callback', [FaceBookController::class, 'callbackFromFacebook'])->name('callback');
});
```

App.php

```
'providers' => [
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

        
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
        'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,

    ])->toArray(),
```

auth.blade.php

```
 <a href="{{ route('facebook.login') }}" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
   <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i>
   Login with Facebook
</a>
```

Until I know the solution

Answer (score 5):

I spent many hours last night trying to figure this out and the issue was in the Facebook App settings, as I did not have the "email" use case permission enabled.

To check this, goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your-app-id/use_cases/ and click the Authentication and account creation > Edit button

[Screenshot: Use cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM7cX.png)

If there is an Add button next to the "email" permission, click it and that should allow the Facebook Socialite Driver to work.

[Screenshot: Add email permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOHN0.png)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you man! Saved me a lot of time. :)

Comment: Thank you. I've struggled with this so many hours. Facebook must give more information at least dev app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your-app-id/use_cases/

then click edit for Authentication and account creation

next scroll down to Permissions

finally click add to email